# Объясните смысл конструкции

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, эту конструкцию на js (т.е. зачем нужна, когда лучше использовать, как обратиться к её элементам), а также смысл if-проверки (ниже):

```
if (!window.Upload) {
    var Upload = {

        init: function(obj, vars, options) {
        //...
        },
        deinit: function(iUpload) {
        //...
        }
    };
}
```

**UPD 1:**

Интересует также тип `Upload`'a.

Comment: Как можно понять смысл конструкции, если в ней ничего нет, многоточий?

Comment: @hindmost , Я имею ввиду, функции, вложенные в var Upload.
что есть Upload? Какой у него тип? Не так давно знаком с js и никогда такого ещё не видел.

Comment: _что есть Upload? Какой у него тип?_ Это все нужно в вопросе писать, вместе со всеми подробностями. Здесь телепатов нет

Comment: @hindmost , комментарии используются для пояснений или уточнения вопроса. Если я этого не написал сразу, значит я не знал, что эта информация необходима.

Comment: _что есть Upload? Какой у него тип?_ - объект

Comment: Комментарии - это временное средство. А что вам сейчас мешает перенести эти подробности в сам вопрос?

Comment: @hindmost , перенесу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!window.Upload) { // если нет глобальной переменной Upload то выполняем код дальше
    var Upload = { // Создаём переменную Upload

        init: function(obj, vars, options) { // Функция инициализации
        //...
        },
        deinit: function(iUpload) {// Функция уничтожения
        //...
        }
    };
}
```

Вызываем функции таким образом:

```
var iUpload = Upload.init(obj, vars, options); // Инициализировали iUpload
Upload.deinit(iUpload); // Уничтожили iUpload
```

Upload это объект.

Comment: А что есть Upload? Как его называть? Это что-то типа класса, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Это или объект или класс. Если добавите контекст, то смогу подробнее сказать

Comment: @R.Matveev, это объект уже. Классов в жс пока нету, есть прототипы и в es6 подобие знакомого ооп синтаксиса.

Comment: Ну я к тому что объект может использоваться как объект — просто как набор функция, а может быть «классом (прототипом)»

Comment: @Mihanik71, ох уж эти сложности с терминологией в js

Comment: @Grundy но ведь все же всё равно понимают о чём разговор идёт)

Comment: @Mihanik71, не всегда

Comment: не перевелись еще телепаты на земле Русской